# Element-wise addition of two matrices/data frames

Tags: r

I have two large data frames with same col names and same row names in the same order. Is there an R function to add element wise the two data frames together ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Element-wise addition is what `+` does with most objects:

```
> d <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)
> d
  x y
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> d2 <- data.frame(z=4:6, w=6:4)
> d + d2
  x  y
1 5 10
2 7 10
3 9 10
```

The names will come from the first data frame, and order of the columns in the two sets does matter.  As yours are in the same order, you should be fine.

You'll get an error if the number of rows or columns differ.