# Element-wise addition of list of data frames in R

Tags: r

[The answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39625864/element-wise-addition-of-two-matrices-data-frames) shows you can add two data frames (with the same dimensions) element-wise using '+'.

I have a list of data frames of the same dimensions, and I would like to return the element-wise sum of all the data frames. Since the length of the list can vary, I do not want to do something like

```
mylist[[1]] + mylist[[2]] + ...
```

I know I can write a loop to calculate the sum, but is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Reduce`

```
Reduce("+", your_list)
```

Example:

```
d1 <- data.frame(x=1:3, y=4:6)
d2 <- data.frame(z=4:6, w=6:4)
l <- list(d1, d2)
Reduce("+", l) 
  x  y
1 5 10
2 7 10
3 9 10
```

Comment: Perfect! I will accept your answer